# Object.MemberwiseCloneメソッドでクローン生成時のstring型メンバはコピーが必要か

Tags: c#

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netcore-3.1
上記URLにてObject.MemberwiseCloneメソッドについて記述がありますが
ここで示されている例ではstring型のメンバフィールドをstring.Copyを使用してコピーしています。

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public Person DeepCopy()
    {
       Person other = (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
       other.IdInfo = new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
       other.Name = String.Copy(Name);
       return other;
    }
}
```

しかし、実際にはMemberwiseClone()を用いて生成したクローンの
stringフィールドを変更しても元のインスタンスには影響を与えません。
また、この例にあるstring.CopyはObsoleteとなっています。

仮に、string型フィールドのみ、または値型とstring型フィールドのみの
クラスであればMemberwiseClone()を用いてクローンを生成するだけで
ディープコピーと同じ状態を得られると考えて問題ないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Object.MemberwiseCloneメソッドでクローン生成時のstring型メンバはコピーが必要か

不要です。string型のインスタンスは内容が変化することがない(immutable,不変である)ため、内容をコピーして新しいインスタンスを作る必要はありません。

> 仮に、string型フィールドのみ、または値型とstring型フィールドのみの
> クラスであればMemberwiseClone()を用いてクローンを生成するだけで
> ディープコピーと同じ状態を得られると考えて問題ないでしょうか。

はい、厳密にはディープコピーではありませんが、実用上その認識で問題ありません。

Answer (score 0):

[`String.Copy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.copy?view=netcore-3.1)に

> 特に、.NET Core 3.0 では文字列インターンが変更されているため、 Copy メソッドは新しい文字列を作成せず、単に既存のインターン文字列への参照を返す場合があります。

とあるように、ディープコピーを実現できない可能性があります。

オブジェクトには様々なコピー要求があり`Object.MemberwiseClone`ではカバーしきれないため利用はあまり推奨されていません。ご自身の望むコピー処理を直接記述されることをお勧めします。例えば、[`String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1#Immutability)は不変なためディープコピーする意義がないかもしれません。